# Integrate the ImageDataGenerator in own customized fit_generator

Tags: machine-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

I want to fit a Siamese CNN with multiple inputs that are stored in my memory and no label (just an arbitrary dummy label). Therefore, I had to write my own data_generator function for using a CNN model in Keras.

My data generator is of the following form

```
class DataGenerator(keras.utils.Sequence):

def __init__(self, train_data, train_triplets, batch_size=32, dim=(128,128), n_channels=3, shuffle=True):
    self.dim = dim
    self.batch_size = batch_size
    #Added
    self.train_data = train_data
    self.train_triplets = train_triplets 
    self.n_channels = n_channels
    self.shuffle = shuffle
    self.on_epoch_end()

def __len__(self):
    'Denotes the number of batches per epoch'
    n_row = self.train_triplets.shape[0]
    return int(np.floor(n_row / self.batch_size))


def __getitem__(self, index): 
    'Generate one batch of data'
    # Generate indexes of the batch
    #print(index)
    indexes = self.indexes[index*self.batch_size:(index+1)*self.batch_size]
    # Find list of IDs      
    list_IDs_temp = self.train_triplets.iloc[indexes,]

    # Generate data
    [anchor, positive, negative] = self.__data_generation(list_IDs_temp)
    y_train = np.random.randint(2, size=(1,2,self.batch_size)).T

    return [anchor,positive, negative], y_train

def on_epoch_end(self):
    'Updates indexes after each epoch'
    n_row = self.train_triplets.shape[0]
    self.indexes = np.arange(n_row)
    if self.shuffle == True:
        np.random.shuffle(self.indexes)

def __data_generation(self, list_IDs_temp):
    'Generates data containing batch_size samples' 
    # anchor positive and negatives: (n_samples, *dim, n_channels)
    # Initialization
    anchor = np.zeros((self.batch_size,*self.dim,self.n_channels))
    positive = np.zeros((self.batch_size,*self.dim,self.n_channels))
    negative = np.zeros((self.batch_size,*self.dim,self.n_channels))

    nrow_temp = list_IDs_temp.shape[0] 
    # Generate data
    for i in range(nrow_temp):
        list_ind = list_IDs_temp.iloc[i,]
        anchor[i] = self.train_data[list_ind[0]]
        positive[i] = self.train_data[list_ind[1]]
        negative[i] = self.train_data[list_ind[2]]   

    return [anchor, positive, negative]
```

where train_data is a list of all images and train triplets a data frame containing image indices to create my inputs containing of a triplet of images.
Now, I want to do some data augmenting for each mini batch supplied to my CNN. I have tried to integrate the ImageDataGenarator of Keras but I couldn't implement it in my code. Is it somehow possible to do it ? I am not very experienced with python and would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

Does [this article](https://medium.com/the-artificial-impostor/custom-image-augmentation-with-keras-70595b01aeac) answer your question?

To put it in a nutshell, Kera's `ImageDataGenerator` lacks flexibility when it comes to personalized batch generators, and the easiest way to still use data augmentation is simply to switch to another data augmentation tool (like the [**`albumentations`**](https://github.com/albumentations-team/albumentations) library described in the previous article, but you could also use [**`imgaug`**](https://github.com/aleju/imgaug) as well).

I just want to warn you that I encountered several issues with `albumentations` (that I described in [this question](https://github.com/albumentations-team/albumentations/issues/650) on GitHub, but for now I still have had no answers), so maybe using `imgaug` is a better idea.

Hope this helps, good luck with your model !